# Get elements of an Array in bash

Tags: bash

I have this vars:

```
REPO_ZERO=('first' 'two'  'three')
REPO_ONE=('1' '2' '3')

REPOS=(
 $REPO_ZERO
 $REPO_ONE
)
```

I have created a loop to iterate them:

```
for REPO in $REPOS
 do
  echo $REPO
done
```

I just get the first element, "firts" and "1", ok, If I type this:

for REPO in $REPOS
     do
      echo $REPO[1]
    done

I get "first[1]" and "1[1]".

If I type this:

```
 for REPO in $REPOS
   do
    echo ${REPO[1]}
   done
```

I get nothing.

What can I do to get the elements inside the loop? I was searching but I dont get nothing that works.

Thanks.

Comment: Bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash has no support for multidimensional arrays.

```
 REPO_ZERO=('first' 'two'  'three')  
 REPO_ONE=('1' '2' '3') 
 REPOS=( $REPO_ZERO $REPO_ONE)
```

it's equal to:

```
 REPO_ZERO=('first' 'two'  'three')  
 REPO_ONE=('1' '2' '3') 
 REPOS=('first' '1')
```

Because `$REPO_ZERO` and `$REPO_ONE` will return first elements of each array.

You can print your array with `echo ${ARRAY[*]}` command

Comment: Thanks, I will change a few thinks and I think that this will works.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of get the functionality of 2d arrays using indirection `${!var}` and a function

```
twod(){
    element="$1[$2]"
    echo "${!element}"
}

REPO_ZERO=('first' 'two'  'three')
REPO_ONE=('1' '2' '3')
REPOS=( 'REPO_ZERO' 'REPO_ONE')

for i in "${REPOS[@]}";do

    twod "$i" 2

done
```

Prints

```
three
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate two arrays with

```
REPOS=( "${REPO_ZERO[@]}" "${REPO_ONE[@]}" )
for repo in "$REPOS[@]}"; do
    echo "$repo"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was said bash does not support multidimensional array, however based on your use case, you can simulate it.

So if you define your array like

```
REPOS=(
"first two three"
"1 2 3")
```

You can display the contents like the following

```
for REPOLINE in "${REPOS[@]}"
do    
   REPO=($REPOLINE)
   for ((i=0;i<=${#REPO[*]};i++));
   do
      echo ${REPO[i]}
   done
done
```

the line

```
REPO=($REPOLINE)
```

passes each line from REPOS array to another array called REPO.

I have used this and works. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions

Comment: _I have used this and works_… mmmhhhh, have you tried it with glob characters? It's a horrible and frowned upon method to split a string.

Comment: I have this line up in the answer _based on your use case_ it helped me solve a problem at hand